# Import R example dataset into excel

Tags: r

I am using the topmodel package in R with the huagrahuma dataset that comes with the package.
I would like to bring all these variables into excel, edit those as per my requirement & then use the base in R.

package & data: https://rdrr.io/cran/topmodel/man/huagrahuma.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For now it is not very clear what you are asking. Please provide code, and details.

Comment: Start out with `library(topmodel);  data(huagrahuma)`  However, this data is _not_ a data frame. You can look at pieces in Excel, but it does not naturally translate to a spreadsheet format.  Try `str(huagrahuma)`   and `head(huagrahuma)` to see what is in the data.

Comment: Thanks Bea; I am providing codes soon: pl check if u can make my life little smoother: thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can save datasets using a command like `write.csv()` or one of the writing functions from the `readr`, `readxl` or `xlsx` packages (for example). Using:

```
?write.csv()
```

Will show you how to use the function. Once you have it saved as a .csv file on your computer, you can open it with Excel and do what you need with it.

**Edit**: Following G5W's comment below, you could try extracting elements of this list and saving those, depending on what you actually want to change. To be honest, with a list structure, you are better off changing the data in R, using any of the `apply` family of functions, or the `purrr` package. R is much better than Excel for transforming/tidying data, so why not use it? :-)

Comment: write.csv will not work for this data.  It is _not_ a data.frame or any other form of rectangular data. It is a list with a mixture of structures.